# CMake Imported Library Target giving undefined giving undefined symbols on Windows

Tags: windows, cmake, libuv

I'm trying to import libuv into my CMake project so I can link it. I have libuv 1.12.0 installed from [here](http://dist.libuv.org/dist/) and I placed it in `C:\Program Files\libuv\`.

```
project(tls-server LANGUAGES C)
set(LIBUV_ROOT_DIR "C:\\Program Files\\libuv")
add_library(libuv SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET libuv PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${LIBUV_ROOT_DIR}\\libuv.dll")
set_property(TARGET libuv PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${LIBUV_ROOT_DIR}\\libuv.lib")
add_executable(tls-server "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.c")
target_link_libraries(tls-server libuv)
```

However, given the above code I am still getting undefined symbol errors in Visual Studio:

[image: Error message]

How can I fix this? I believe the paths are all correct. I'm also using Windows 10.

Comment: You **cannot** use `.lib` file on MinGW. `.lib` is for Visual Studio compiler and linker, but MinGW and its gcc want `.a` (or `.dll.a`). With pure C language it is possible to create `.a` from `.def` file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I see. However, I get the same error using the visual studio generator, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the issue.

Firstly I reinstalled the binaries from the target library (libuv). Then, I made sure that my `cmake` was generating x64 project files by using `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"`. That was sufficient to get rid of the undefined symbols error. Then all I needed to do was copy the libuv.dll file to the same directory as the executable file, and everything ran fine.

If anyone knows why this error occured, please comment so you can help out other people in the future target the cause of the error better.

Answer (score 1):

Never hardcode library paths or names like this in CMake.

Instead use the [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/find_library.html) command, which does a decent job of notifying you early if something is wrong with the provided library.

On Windows in particular, since there are no default locations where libraries are located on the system (something like the `/usr/local/lib` on *nix systems), you may want to provide an additional customization point for the library's location. I personally like to use environment variables for this, but a normal CMake option will also do:

```
project(tls-server LANGUAGES C)

find_library(LIBUV_LIBRARIES NAMES uv libuv 
     HINTS $ENV{LIBUV_ROOT})

add_executable(tls-server ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.c)
target_link_libraries(tls-server ${LIBUV_LIBRARIES})
```

Note that CMake in general never takes care of copying runtime dependencies to the correct place! That is, if `libuv` was built as a `.dll`, you must ensure that that `.dll` is in the correct path when running the program.

You can of course manually insert a copy command in CMake for getting all the dlls into place, but that can be quite cumbersome. Unfortunately there is no more comfortable solution for this problem right now.

Using imported targets here is possible, but really only pays off if you need to pass on more complex properties to the depending target. In my experience, imported targets work best if the dependency provides a [fully-fledged package config file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#using-packages). Writing imported targets manually is often not worth the trouble in terms of additional complexity.

Comment: How does this post help with the **problem** ("undefined reference") ? *Improving* the code in the question is good intention, but this is not a main purpose of the *answer post*. I have seen related question on meta recently.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The undefined reference goes undetected because CMake does not check hard-coded paths. By improving the code, the underlying is problem is solved as a side-effect, which imho is a much better approach than painfully debugging the problem, while leaving the broken CMake as it is. StackOverflow is not a free debugging service.

Comment: *Effectively* your code **does the same** (at least, for Visual Studio) as one in the question post. Specifying *HINTS* or *PATHS* is just cross-platform way for hard-coded paths: this only allows to autoselect library's prefix/suffix. (Assuming, that you don't have system installation of the library). `StackOverflow is not a free debugging service.` - this is for cases of "bunch of code without any comment". Actually, I guess more 90% questions on SO about detection of the problems in existing code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Well, it does eliminate the cases where we accidentally mix MinGW and VS toolchains, as well as the one where the library file is not present at the hardcoded location. After that there is not too much left that can still go wrong and certainly nothing that can be solved without resorting to some amount of guesswork.

Comment: `... nothing that can be solved without resorting to some amount of guesswork.` - You may request additional information in the comments to the question post. Of cource, there are questions where requesting additional information is not an option, so we close them. But in given question the author is **able** (he is somehow familiar with tools he uses) and **wants** (there is already some additional information) to provide information which is currently missing. BTW, many *valid* answers for some question are acutally result of "guesswork".

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sure, I agree with you there. But let's first wait if this is one of the 90% cases where the proposed solution works and only go down that road if it's actually necessary.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you both, I'll see if this works when I have a look later.

Comment: I just tried this, no luck - still getting the same "undefined symbols" error in visual studio. I realised that the header file I was including didn't mark the functions as `__declspec(dllimport)`, but after adding a define for that purpose the new undefined symbol I get is `__imp__uv_chdir` (as opposed to `_uv_chdir`). Do you have any more suggestions? I have a feeling that it's something to do with the fact that there's an import `.lib` library along with the accompanying `.dll` file (I haven't seen that before).

Comment: @HexCoder You need to link against the import library (.lib). Unlike Linux `.so`s, you cannot link against Windows `.dll`s. Ensure that the dll was compiled in a way that is compatible with your depending project's ABI. This is very easy to get wrong due to the number of possible combinations of compile options affecting this on Windows. Then also ensure names are mangled correctly (which might mean: not at all, for C libs) so the linker looks for the correct symbols.

Comment: I was under the impression that the code in my original post would handle the linking with the `.lib` file correctly. I also don't think the name mangling would be an issue since the library I am linking to is pure C (the same as my project). I'll check that I'm using the right version of the libraries. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Ok, I believe that I have finally gotten it working. Firstly I reinstalled the binaries from the target library (libuv). Then, I made sure that my `cmake` was generating x64 project files by using `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"`. That was sufficient to get rid of the undefined symbols error. Then all I needed to do was copy the `libuv.dll` file to the same directory as the executable file, and everything ran fine. I'm still not really sure why I was getting that error lol. Thanks both for your help! @Tsyvarev

Comment: @HexCoder Glad you figured it out. As to why you were getting the linker error: It seems most likely to me that you somehow mismatched the configuration of the binaries that you downloaded with the compiler settings of your project (eg. download x64 binaries but use them with an x86 project).